# Rotating words in a string in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, rotation, cpu-word

The program is supposed to take a sentence inputted by the user such as "I am very hungry" and then ask a number of words to rotate. If the number was 2 the new output would be "very hungry I am". This is my code so far but I seem to have an error. When I run the code, this appears: java.util.InputMismatchException. There is also some other information that appears under it but I am not sure what it means. This is my code so far.

```
import java.util.*;
public class WordRotation
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a sentence");

     if(input.hasNext());
    {
      String s = input.next();

      String[] words = s.split(" ");

      System.out.println("Enter number of words to be rotated");
      int rotation = input.nextInt();

      for (int i = 0;i < words.length;i++)
      {
        System.out.print(words[(i + words.length - rotation)%words.length] + " ");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to change my if statement to a while statement but the code never outputs anything, it just keeps loading.

Comment: can you check the code without the `if` statement?

Comment: _"There is also some other information that appears under it but I am not sure what it means."_ -- that's the stack trace for the exception. Generally it is better to post the entire stack trace verbatim rather than just the exception name. What line is throwing the exception?

Comment: you have a `;` after `if` was it intentional?

Comment: Thank you. I missed that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Change `String s = input.next();` to `String s = input.nextLine();`

---

Yeah, it is actually a solution because after we hit enter, there is a `\n` still left in stream after we hit `Enter` and `.nextInt()` reads that `\n` **and** your number. If we use `input.nextLine()` instead of `input.next()` we will capture that `\n` and `input.nextInt()` will read next integer without `\n`.

There is more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/7056782/1366360

Comment: That won't change anything.

Comment: @tintinmj - This actually is the solution because `input.next()` reads the next _token_, not the entire sentence (or line). That leaves the input at the second word (assuming the default delimiter of whitespace), which then causes an `InputMismatchException` in the call to `input.nextInt()`.

Comment: @lancemanfv Ok in this case it's true. But OP should know this is a hack and may not be useful in future.

Comment: @tintinmj - Why is it a hack? The change makes the program read according to what's expected.

Comment: @tintinmj no, it's not a hack, check out updated post for explanations. Everything is right - we press `Enter`, Scanner reads `I am hungry` and input stream receives new line symbol `\n`. The next thing we will read, no matter which `.nextXXX()` we invoke, will be that `\n` but we will crash if we will try to return that `\n` as Integer, Double or whatever except string. Invoking `input.next()` once more to skip that `\n` would be a hack:)

Comment: I upvoted it long time ago, i was just suggesting you to make your explanation clear.

Comment: @tintinmj No offence, I didn't say that that was you but that -1 upset me.

Comment: @user3015645 try to always wrap your `input.nextXXX()` with `if(input.hasNextXXX())` and set some log or `system.out.print` message for `else` so you can easily find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read again from input after your

```
  System.out.println("Enter number of words to be rotated");
```

add this line

```
Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
  int rotation = input2.nextInt();
```

Comment: Why not use `input` as OP is already doing? The problem is that OP isn't reading the entire first line, just the first word of the sentence.